# Laravel 4 with Cartalyst\Sentry , provide generic Interface

Tags: oop, inheritance, laravel, laravel-4

I want to use Sentry for User Authentication in my project and i set it up working already.

My idea is to provide a kind of adapter to change the implementation later. As we may plan to change to LDAP later, i want to call all the functions on my own class.

I set up a new Facade and a Class called `UMS`, short for `User Management System` i then want to call `UMS::check()` instead of `Sentry::check()`

How do i do this properly? I thought of just doing:

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Dashboard;

class UMS extends \Sentry {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }

}

?>
```

What doesnt work so far, because i get a `Cannot call constructor` Exception. I am a little bit confuse because i feel Laravel kind of abuses the Facade pattern to enable late binding. Usually one facade refers to only one class. I simply want to change the implementation behind `UMS` later and therefore not calling `Sentry` in my code. But i should be able to call all methods on `Sentry` as usual. Maybe the solution is obvious

Comment: or should i simply change the UserProvider by an LDAP One?

Comment: From what I understand, you want to use dependency injection when creating adapters, not inheritance. So I would inject the required Sentry library/class into the new class, and then call whatever method(s) you need in your adapter(s).

Comment: yes this is what i have done so far, so i call the sentry methods from my own class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Laravel 4, to properly extend a Class and create a new Facade you must:

Create your new class based on another one:

```
<?php namespace AntonioRibeiro\UserManagementSystem;

class UMS extends \Cartalyst\Sentry\Sentry {

    // For now your UMS class is identical to Sentry, so you must have nothing here, right?

}
```

Create a ServiceProvider, wich will instantiate your class:

```
<?php namespace AntonioRibeiro\UserManagementSystem;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class UMSServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['ums'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            // Once the authentication service has actually been requested by the developer
            // we will set a variable in the application indicating such. This helps us
            // know that we need to set any queued cookies in the after event later.
            $app['sentry.loaded'] = true;

            return new UMS(
                $app['sentry.user'],
                $app['sentry.group'],
                $app['sentry.throttle'],
                $app['sentry.session'],
                $app['sentry.cookie'],
                $app['request']->getClientIp()
            );
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return array('ums');
    }

}
```

Create the Facade:

```
<?php namespace AntonioRibeiro\UserManagementSystem;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade as IlluminateFacade;

class UMSFacade extends IlluminateFacade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'ums'; }

}
```

Add your Service Provider to the list in app/config/app.php:

```
'providers' => array(
    ...
    'AntonioRibeiro\UserManagementSystem\UMSServiceProvider',
),
```

Add your Facade to the list of aliases in app/config/app.php:

```
'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'UMS'             => 'AntonioRibeiro\UserManagementSystem\UMSFacade',
),
```

Update the autoloaded classes:

```
composer du --optimze
```

And use it:

```
var_dump( UMS::check() );
var_dump( UMS::getUser() );
```

Comment: Seems to be much better, i will try to implement it soon! Thanks

Comment: There's no right place for them. Create a folder on app/, add them there, add that folder to `composer.json/autoload/classmap` section and run `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution for now, dont know if there is a much better solution, but it works, just calling the function on Sentry through my own class

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Dashboard;

use Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Laravel\Sentry as Sentry;

class UMS {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public static function check() {
        return Sentry::check();
    }

    public static function authenticate($credentials, $rememberme) {
        return Sentry::authenticate($credentials, $rememberme);
    }

    public static function logout () {
        return Sentry::logout();
    }

    public static function getUser() {
        return Sentry::getUser();
    }

    public static function getUserProvider() {
        return Sentry::getUserProvider();
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: This solution is sick.

Answer (score 0):

You could also inject your app's instance of Sentry into your class. The below is for a service provider (in the register function), but it's similar:

```
$this->app['myPackage.user'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
    {
        return new myClass($app['sentry']);
    });

$this->app['myAlias'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
    {

        return new myPackage($app['myPackage.user']);
    });
```

Then, in myClass:

```
class myClass {

    protected $sentry;

    function __construct($sentry){
        $this->sentry = $sentry;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->sentry->getUser();
    }

}
```

And add your functions as necessary.